# Get temperature of CPU (Intel Core i5) in FreeBSD

Tags: temperature, freebsd, intel-core-i5

Does anyone know how to get the temperature of an Intel Core i5 processor in FreeBSD?

Relevant info:

- Motherboard: *Asus P8P67 Deluxe*
- CPU: *Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500*
- OS: *FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE (64bit)*

I've tried:

- `sysctl -a` ⇒ nothing about CPU-temp there
- `mbmon` ⇒ outputs: `No Hardware Monitor found!! InitMBInfo: Unknown error: 0`

I've successfully used `mbmon` on previous rigs with older hardware, but I can't get it to work with this setup. I've tried all "access methods" (options `-V`, `-S`, `-I`, `-A`).

Comment: You may need to load smbus (`kldload smbus`) and/or other modules to get mbmon to work. It depends on the chipset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
% kldload coretemp
% sysctl -a |grep temper
dev.cpu.0.temperature: 60
dev.cpu.1.temperature: 60
dev.cpu.2.temperature: 64
dev.cpu.3.temperature: 64
```

Also check if FreeBSD has modules for your ACPI-chip:

```
ls /boot/kernel |grep ^acpi
acpi.ko
acpi_aiboost.ko
acpi_asus.ko
acpi_dock.ko
acpi_fujitsu.ko
acpi_ibm.ko
acpi_panasonic.ko
acpi_sony.ko
acpi_toshiba.ko
acpi_video.ko
```

Comment: Perfect, `kldload coretemp`did it. Thank you very much! (And yes, I try to always accept when I've received the best answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

On an ASUSTeK motherboard, apart from the already referenced [coretemp(4)](http://mdoc.su/f82/coretemp.4), you could also try [aibs(4)](http://mdoc.su/f82/aibs.4), too.

```
# kldload coretemp ; kldload acpi ; kldload aibs
```

```
%sysctl dev.{cpu,aibs} | fgrep temp
```